# Java Android after scroll to bottom and fetch new data always go to first data/page (top recycle view)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, httpurlconnection, fetch

After fetching new data, the application always go to first page. As a result, I have to scroll to the bottom (again) to see new data on my recycle view.

#### Code

This is my code. How do I solve my problem?

```js
package tonnyferiandi.lastproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class tab_feed extends Fragment {

    private List<tab_feedItem> feedsList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private tab_feedAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Bitmap photone;
    private Bitmap photono;
    private boolean load = true;
    public int page=0;
    public View v;
    public String url;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_feed, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Downloading data from below url
        url = "http://tukoe.com/feed/getfeed.php?page="+String.valueOf(page);
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
        return v;
    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("RecyclerView", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (result == 1) {
                scroll();
                page++;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                tab_feedItem item = new tab_feedItem();
                if(!post.getString("title").equals(null)){
                    load = true;
                }
                item.setTitle(post.optString("title"));
                photone = decodeBase64(post.optString("photo"));
                int outWidth;
                int outHeight;
                int inWidth = photone.getWidth();
                int inHeight = photone.getHeight();
                if(inWidth > inHeight){
                    outWidth = 768;
                    outHeight = (inHeight * 768) / inWidth;
                } else {
                    outHeight = 768;
                    outWidth = (inWidth * 768) / inHeight;
                }
                photono = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photone, outWidth, outHeight, false);
                item.setThumbnail(photono);

                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input){
        byte[] decodeByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeByte, 0, decodeByte.length);
    }

    public void scroll(){
        adapter = new tab_feedAdapter(getActivity(), feedsList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (load) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                            load = false;
                            url = "http://tukoe.com/feed/getfeed.php?page="+String.valueOf(page);
                            new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Which part must I change?
- Which part does make it go to top/first page or first data on a recycle view?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are recreating the adapter when you complete fetching the new data. This is what is causing you to scroll back to the top. I recommend not recreating the adapter, but rather updating the items and notifying the adapter of the change.

First I'd like to point out that you are referencing data in the Fragment from within your AsyncTask. This is a bad idea as it can result in concurrency issues. Your AsyncTask should only reference it's own variables. I would recommend having your AsyncTask result return a List of tab_feed items that you can use to update your UI with.

To start you should only call your `scroll()` method once when the Fragment is created. It is fine to use an empty array when you initialize the adapter since we are going to be updated them soon anyway.

In your fragment when the fetch is complete:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<tab_feedItem> result) {
        // Download complete. Let us update UI
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (result != null) {
            adapter.updateItems(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And inside your adapter:

```
public void updateItems(List<tab_feedItem> feedItems){
    this.items.clear();
    this.items.addAll(feeditems);
}
```

This should fix the issue you have. A faster solution would be to save the scroll position and load it again once the adapter is recreated. I would advise against this though as it does not solve your potential concurrency issues and it is sloppy. The above recommendations will require some significant changes to your code but it is the more correct way of implementing what you are trying to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to call scroll. The best way to expose a method to update list of data, whenever you got new data just update the list of your adapter and call notifyDataSetChange.

```
adapter.setData(feedsList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

That's it you need to do, and your list will add all your new data at bottom.

Hope it will work for you :)